Convert Word Docx to PDF headlessly?
I'm currently using doc2pdf python library to convert some Word docx files to pdf.
from docx2pdf import convert

docx_file = '/tmp/One_of_hundreds.docx'
file_ext = os.path.splitext(docx_file)[1]
if file_ext.lower() == '.docx':
    # we'll need to convert this to a PDF
    pdf_path = os.path.splitext(docx_file)[0] + '.pdf'
    convert(docx_file, pdf_path)

Unfortunately, this spins up MS-Word, which I think would be jarring for a user to see, especially if it happens multiple times (in the hundreds). Is there no way to suppress the Word UI (I'm on MacOS if that helps)? Additionally, this also spins up a dialog asking for permissions, which mercifully happens only once, is there no way to prevent that?

Do you mean that you use this? https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/
